# Element Numeric Position for Array

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, trino

I know in Spark/Impala, you can use `array_column.POS`
to represent the numeric position of each element within the array.

How can you write this for Presto? Doesn't look like `Array_Position` works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subscript operator](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#subscript-operator) to access an element by position:

```sql
WITH t(array_column) AS (VALUES array['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'])
SELECT array_column[2] 
FROM t
```

=>

```
 _col0
-------
 quick
(1 row)
```

You can use [`array_position`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array_position) to find the position of a value within the array:

```sql
WITH t(array_column) AS (VALUES array['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox'])
SELECT array_position(array_column, 'quick') 
FROM t
```

=>

```
 _col0
-------
     2
(1 row)
```